# Special phone and e-mail characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string-parsing

I am parsing web pages by .NET (c#, HtmlAgilityPack). There are some values in the special format in the web page code (phone, email). Target values are "+420 221 513 222" and "revize@secar.cz" for instance but in html source code the values are like

```
<span class="p none">420%8722%AC1%87513%87%AC222</span>

<a class="e none">rev%DBize%DB%A7se%DBcar%DB%96cz</a>
```

I think I am missing something. I tried to use replace function etc. but to no avail. Can somebody help me with converting this values to right string values? (regex?)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: They are trying to protect their data against people like you.

Comment: @CodeCaster - And they would have gotten away with it if it wasn't for those pesky kids! I agree this does look to be scraping contact details for some sort of telemarketing

Comment: Oh, I see. You'r right. Each time the page is loaded there is a different code. So it looks like a problem for me (there must be some javascript de-codding, right?) Btw, the page is for instance http://topkontakt.idnes.cz/f/secar-bohemia-a-s/1405/  Ok, thank you, P.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(S)
```

This can be found in the System.Web namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. You're looking for `Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)`. However, it doesn't quite decode all of it at the same time. So what you need to do is use it in a loop, like this:

```
public static string DecodeUrlString(this string url)
{
    string newUrl;
    while ((newUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)) != url)
        url = newUrl;
    return newUrl;
}
```